# JetBrains IDE : Where can I note my changes before commiting?

Tags: git, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using PhpStorm on a project and, often, I have to look at all the files that I've modified since the previous commit to remember what I've done.

Is there a feature that would enable to note what I've achieved without doing a commit ? I mean, I would be writing some code to debug a little thing that doesn't need any commit, add a new feature, change another little thing and then commit.

Where could I write somewhere my evolutions in the IDE ? I'd like to be able to write somewhere, like on a papernote :

1. fixed this
2. added this feature
3. changed the position of this element

And then, for my commit, I'd group all this information and summarize them in the commit message.

I know I could do it with papernotes or with a Word but I think that it'd be really nice if the JetBrains IDE offer this feature.

I hope I've been clear, if I haven't, tell me !

Comment: Commit more often. For every little modifications you do. No need to duplicate git features.

Comment: If you commit often, you don't need such kind of notes. You just look at the diff before committing and you know what you've done.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, you can add a comment to a commit in Git.  Besides the diff, this can help to make it clear what was done.  You can provide a link to an issue tracker such as Jira.

Comment: If you want to "accumulate" work while still having a single commit, do a normal commit the first time you want to start accumulating, and then use commit --amend over and over updating the commit message to add whatever you did since last commit. Not the best thing to do if you ask me, but still possible.

Comment: `git status` would let you know which files have changed.  It doesn't require a commit to do.  Also, do you use the graphical side of the version control in the IDE, or work through the terminal?

Comment: I knew that you would tell me to commit more often, but that's really not what I want to do. Like I said in above, I don't want to commit if, like it happened this week, I changed a date format (I forgot to applied a function on the date) or if I changed a little UI component while, in the same time, I'm working on a new feature. I know all the stuff I can do with Git (one of you meant implicitly the list feature I think) but it's really not what I'm looking for. I would really like to have something that would offer me the ability to save somewhere the changes I've done without commit.

Comment: @Edmundo This would be closer that what I want to do but I agree, it's not the best thing to do.

Comment: @gabe3886 I'm using the GUI of the IDE but I can use the terminal. I used to work with the terminal before but the GUI of the JetBrains IDE for the VCS integration is really great so now I don't use the terminal too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question. I discovered this morning that everything I write in the "commit message" section in PhpStorm is always saved. So now I can write everything I've done step by step in the commit message and it will be saved without commit.

This example represents what I'm now able to do :

1. refactor a bit of code, not enough to have to commit
2. open commit dialog box and write what I've done (the refactoring) **without commit**
3. continue to work on the feature that I've to create and reach a milestone or a point where I'm ok to commit
4. open commit dialog box and write what I've added after what I wrote before and commit

This perfectly answers to my request so it's perfect !

Thanks for those who offered their help !